# UITabBar in iOS 7 -- touch issues

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, ios7

I'm having a weird occurance with my app in iOS 7 (using the GM build).

I have four tabs, and I have a customized tab bar, with background, icons, etc. I have my code below for setting up tab bar properly:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bar.png"]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_selected.png"]];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I have four tabs, and when the user selects any of the last three tabs, everything works fine. But when the user tries to go back to the first tab, the tab switches, but the selection doesn't switch. It still shows previous tab was selected. If they tap again, then it switches. Is there any other change for iOS 7 I should be aware of? It appears iOS 7 is losing track of touches here and there and I was not able to find anything else.

Comment: You could try to code it so that when the user touches the first tab, you programmatically press the button again. I wouldn't though, because if it gets fixed, then you just put in your own bug. I would submit a bug report to Apple though. That's what beta testers are for, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got that too and am pretty sure it's a bug in ios 7

Comment: Right now the only (temporary) solution I can think of is to check if it's iOS7 an then do the following on the first tab: `[(UITabBarController*)self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];`. This will set the first tab selected. Ugly, but works.